# Python - Get a group from the highest column value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
Col_A   Col_B   Col_C   Cold_D  Score
A   B   C   1   1
A   B   C   NULL    4
A   B   C   10  3
```

I want to extract only the row with the highest score value groupped by Col_A, Col_B and Col_C.

Basically I need to extract this:

```
Col_A   Col_B   Col_C   Cold_D  Score
A   B   C   NULL    4
```

I tried with this code:

```
df = df.groupby(['Col_A','Col_B','Col_C'])['Score'].nlargest(1)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> builtins.KeyError: 'Score'

I was confirmed, and I got the score column on my df.

What I am doing wrong? How can I make the above filter?

Comment: Use: `df.groupby(['Col_A','Col_B','Col_C'])['Score'].nlargest(1)`

Comment: sorry, I forgot to put the groupBy on the question but the issue was returned with the groupBy method. I already update the question

Comment: Seems like you entered `score` instead of `Score`. Notice the capital S.

Comment: same error... I don't know if I can give the score column instead of a function

Comment: Maybe try to remove whitespacs in your column: `df['Score'] = df['Score'].str.strip()`

Comment: @PedroAlves if `df.filter(like='score').columns` returns score column, you will be able to see if the column has spaces. follow what Erfan says then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values('Score').drop_duplicates(['Col_A','Col_B','Col_C'],keep='last')
Out[113]: 
  Col_A Col_B Col_C  Cold_D  Score
1     A     B     C     NaN      4
```